# Security provider not registered during Functional Tests

Tags: mule, esb

We are using Basic Authentication in RestFul webservices deployed on Mule, security powered by in-built Spring Security. We are using Mule 3.3.0.

We have broken our mflow into 2 different parts - main.xml and connector.xml. The reason being while running functional tests we pass another mflow connector-test.xml instead of connector.xml, where all endpoints like AMQ etc are stubbed. However for Rest we are still using proper endpoints. 
In our Mule Functional tests we use apache commons httpclient to make restful WS calls to these endpoints, wait for response and then check if it passed tests.

The same functionality works fine in mule standalone - i.e. rest webservice gets deployed fine and we can make http rest requests - it gets basic authenticated and then returns response. However while doing authentication during functional tests it fails with message

```
Exception stack is:
1. There is no Security Provider reqistered called "org.mule.security.DefaultMuleAuthentication" (org.mule.api.security.SecurityProviderNotFoundException)
  org.mule.security.MuleSecurityManager:107 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/SecurityProviderNotFoundException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.SecurityProviderNotFoundException: There is no Security Provider reqistered called "org.mule.security.DefaultMuleAuthentication"
      at org.mule.security.MuleSecurityManager.authenticate(MuleSecurityManager.java:107)
      at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:134)
      at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:58)
      at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:56)
      at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.doFilter(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:49)
      at org.mule.processor.SecurityFilterMessageProcessor.process(SecurityFilterMessageProcessor.java:52)
      at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:43)
      at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:43)
      at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:192)
      at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:174)
      at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:166)
      at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageReceiver.routeMessage(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:153)
      at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:310)
      at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker$1.process(HttpMessageReceiver.java:305)
      at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:20)
      at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:34)
      at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:18)
      at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:58)
      at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
      at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:54)
      at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:44)
      at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
      at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:52)
      at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
      at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:17)
      at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:113)
      at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:34)
      at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.doRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:304)
      at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.processRequest(HttpMessageReceiver.java:250)
      at org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageReceiver$HttpWorker.run(HttpMessageReceiver.java:163)
      at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:311)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**Any idea why the Security Provider is not getting registered?**

Here are the settings..

**Content of main.xml**

```
 <flow name="RestFlow" doc:name="RestFlow">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="restEndPoint" mimeType="text/xml">
            <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="easervices-realm" />
        </inbound-endpoint>

            <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
 <component>
            <spring-object bean="createCompany"/>            
        </component>
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="activateNumbers"/>            
        </component>
 </jersey:resources>
</flow>
    ........
```

As you can see the security bit is injected in the RestFlow as above.
The rest of security settings are done in the connector.xml(live) or connector-test.xml(test)

**Content of connector-test.xml** - Point to be noted while deploying in memory for running functional tests Rest endpoint is deployed on port 8098 though that should have nothing to do with security

```
<spring:beans>
      <spring:import resource="classpath:spring/external-service-config-stub.xml" />

      <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                  <ss:password-encoder hash="sha" />
                  <ss:user-service id="userService">
                        <ss:user name="adminportal" password="0314795e56347590b54b7da2afba3456fgcd4968"
                              authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                  </ss:user-service>

            </ss:authentication-provider>
      </ss:authentication-manager>
      <ss:global-method-security
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
      </spring:beans>

<http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
            port="8098" path="mypath" name="restEndPoint" doc:name="HTTP" />
<mule-ss:security-manager>
            <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
                  name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
      </mule-ss:security-manager>
```

**content of connector.xml** - Point to note while deploying in mule-standalone Rest is exposed on port 8088 and and real Spring services are injected(though they have nothing to do with security)

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:spring/external-service-config.xml" />

    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
         <ss:authentication-provider>
                  <ss:password-encoder hash="sha" />
                  <ss:user-service id="userService">
                        <ss:user name="adminportal" password="0314795e56347590b54b7da2afba3456fgcd4968"
                              authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                  </ss:user-service>

            </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
    <ss:global-method-security
        pre-post-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="enabled" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config/mule-config.properties" />
    </spring:beans>

<http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
        port="8088" path="mypath" name="restEndPoint" mimeType="text/xml"
        doc:name="HTTP" />
<mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
            name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
```

**Invoking code in our Functional Test code that makes the http rest request while running tests.**

```
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 8098, "easervices-realm"),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("adminportal",
                        "thepassword"));
        httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPolicy.AUTH_SCHEME_PRIORITY,
                Collections.singleton(AuthPolicy.BASIC));
        final PostMethod meth = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8098/horizon"
                + url);
        meth.setDoAuthentication(true);
        meth.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xml, "text/xml",
                "ISO-8859-1"));
        // meth.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        httpClient.executeMethod(meth);
```

Kindly help. The same security setting is used in connector.xml and when the app is deployed in standalone mule 3.3.0 it deploys fine and does basic auth fine too. Somehow the security provider isn't getting registered when running Mule Functional tests where the mule server is started in memory and application deployed for the test with test config.

Comment: Can you name the different snippets (file names) and show how is `getConfigResources()` coded?

Comment: Hi David this the method protected                              String getConfigResources() {

  return "main.xml,connector-test.xml";
 }                                                              For the Live deployment in mule standalone we configure in mule-deploy.properties as                  config.resources=main.xml,connector.xml                              As you can see for tests we use connector-test.xml so that we can stub out ActiveMQ connector and some Service layer classes which are spring injected. Any help is deeply appreciated. looking forward to it

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit your post and clearly show what belongs to `main.xml` and `connector-test.xml` in the configuration snippets?

Comment: Thanks David. I have edited my post accordingly. Please do let me know if you need any more info. We badly want to incorporate Spring security but the failing tests are holding us back.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please check that the Spring dependencies versions are consistent with each other and consistent to what Mule expects? I have add strange registry issues (ie beans not loaded) with projects that had inconsistent Spring versions in their Maven dependencies.

Comment: Sure David will do. But what is confusing me is if the same application deployed on same version of mule standalone works fine how come it doesn't work fine when I am running it during Functional tests. Is there any documentation around whether Functional Tests actually have any restrictions on Security side of things?

Comment: The classpath and classloader layout of functional tests have enough difference with the standalone ones that it can cause this kind of trouble. And no, there's no restriction on security as far as testing is concerned.

Comment: Thanks David. By that I guess you mean the classes loaded by tests will be down to the maven configs. All of the mule related jars are in "provided" scope. I will double check the spring ones and report back

Comment: I have tested the same all my dependencies are Spring 3.1.0 related as mule core 3.3.0 depends on as well. From the error log it seems while trying to do the authentication it is unable to find the registered security provider which is Spring security for basic auth in this case. Any more clues? I have got the xml config and client code in the question itself. If you need any more info kindly do let me know. Thanks again

Comment: One way to get around this is not to load the security aspect of the restendpoint while running functional tests. So the security injection was completely moved to connector.xml from main.xml and in connector-test.xml ignored the security config. However that is a really bad approach. As I can't write tests to check method level security as the functional tests are not spring-secured anymore :(

Comment: I have built a Mule config similar to yours (Jersey, Mule + Spring Security) and I have no problem running functional tests with the HTTP client code snippet you shared above (using Mule 3.3.1). So... can you step debug in `MuleSecurityManager.authenticate(...)` in order to see if the problem is due to an empty `providers` collection or the fact no provider supports the passed `authentication`?

Comment: ok. Thanks David - That means something funny happening on my side as you say you used the same snippets and they work. I can debug remotely for standalone instances - not sure I could do the same for tests as well. I will see if I can use Mule Studio to run the test and then try and run the test in debug mode. Thanks again. Will report back my findings soon

Comment: In Studio, place a breakpoint in the first line of the said method and "Debug As" "JUnit test" to get started. I'm really curious to hear what's happening in your environment. Note that I'm using Mule 3.3.1 and plain Eclipse, not Studio.

Comment: Thanks David. I bumped into the huge classpath error trying to run the Junit test in MuleStudio. Had been tied up today so couldn't do much tests. However - I moved the line <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="easervices-realm" /> from main.xml to connector.xml and connector-test.xml and now the tests all run fine. I no longer get the SecurityProviderNotFoundException any more. So all spring security settings are only in connector xmls - both for live and tests. But then there is a gotcha- Even if I am passing wrong password for a user it is working so still need to see. Will get back tmorrow

Comment: To add - the wrong password works only while running tests. When I send a request to a deployed app in mule standalone it does not work as expected and throws the Bad Credentials error. Makes me feel though the Security Provider gets loaded now - somehow spring security isn't kicking in. The client does send basic auth creds in the http request though as shown in the question above. I will try to do a remote debug in the test if possible tomorrow - or need to manually add jars needed for the unit test and remove the maven classpath dependency which is bloating up the classpath & eclipse fails

Comment: Here is what I did. I create Remote Java Application and listened on port 5005 for the Test. Next I ran the test standlone using maven commandline with -Dmaven.surefire.debug and the test waited until I debugged in Mulestudio. Now I see in MuleSecurityManager.authenticate() is the providers itself is empty. Also I had reverted the change mentioned above - i.e. I put the <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="easervices-realm" /> back in main.xml as by putting that in connector-test.xml I felt Security wasn't kicking in at all. At least in this case it tried to do the Authentication. Any clues?

Comment: Wow - as soon as I move all security related settings from connector-test.xml to main.xml the it started working fine and Security Provider kicked in - i.e. providers no longer empty. Makes me wonder if I am passing 2 xmls to getConfigResources() like "main.xml,connector-test.xml" - somehow it is not able to load the providers if they are split in 2 different xmls. Is this how you set up your test as well David? i.e. split the mule:ss and ss: configs in 2 different xmls as explained in the original question? keen on understanding how this is an issue during Tests but works fine in standalone!

Comment: Also this approach means I cannot use different users for live and Test as all settings are configured in main.xml while ideally I should have been able to abstract those out to connector xml files.

Comment: `mule:ss` and `ss:` are **not** split in two different configs in the original question, it's just the Jersey flow that is in another configuration. Anyhow, I've tried all sorts of variants with `mule:ss`, `ss:` and the Jersey flow split across two XML files and it works in all cases for me. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry what I meant was the security stuff was split in 2 xmls. So <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="easervices-realm" />  was in teh inbound endpoint section of the RestFlow. And the Security Manager and provider config etc was in connector xmls. Since you say you have tried all combinations and it works I will need to find why it doesn't when I split the security configs in 2 xmls. As of now i have got it working by having all security related stuff in main.xmk but ideally whether we want the security or not and what config we want should be in the connector. anyways thanks a lot David!

Comment: @Soumya Your comment above regarding moving the security settings into one config was very helpful. Thank you! I was having the exact same issue and it resolved it for me as well! :-)